# Declined Flag Reasoning

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

As an active user of the Review queue (at least, in the Triage and Low Quality Posts sections), it has been disheartening to have received 3 declined flags in the last 48 hours.

Upon conducting a review earlier, I was presented with the **Your last flag was declined**.... etc message, which I am fine with.

The issue I have is the message that the moderator left for me, which is:

> declined - Please stop gaming flags.

The low quality post review took place on this question: (since deleted)

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6631802

The other two posts I reference at the start of this discussion also occurred whilst reviewing low quality posts - as with the above, I voted correctly (and the outcome was unanimous) and the posts have since been deleted.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6618842

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6618791

The message I was left by the moderator was:

> declined - already handled

The *only* reason I can think of as to why this has happened, is because sometimes when I flag an answer, the *only* option the window offers me is:

> other (needs ♦ moderator attention)

As there are no other options, I'd type in **not an answer** and submit the flag.

Am I at fault for not being presented with the correct number of options in the flag window? Should I not flag posts in this situation, then?

Comment: Also, you don't need to re-flag posts that are already in VLQ

Comment: `As there are no other options` is showing you the NAA has already been handled, the post is already deleted at this moment.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET one (and I think really good) reason to re-flag VLQ is to give extra guarantee for the post you believe to be garbage to be saved from deletion by a random "Looks OK" dropped by some senseless reviewer, see eg [A single “looks good” should not mean the post is “good”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204691/165773) (worth keeping in mind that there are 30,000 users eligible to review)

Comment: Another thing that occurred: you loaded the question page 5 seconds before it was deleted.  We need to better surface when a question's state changes before you do an action like flagging (or even prevent flagging in this scenario).

Comment: Adding to what @JarrodDixon said, I would suggest (as a feature reuqest) that it would be helpful to display something ("Some flags are not available for this question because of ...") when there are limited options. The reason for this is really not obvious, if you don't already know it.

Comment: @JarrodDixon I had a similar experience to OP and agree with you wholeheartedly

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're not presented with any of the other flag options then it means that none of those options are valid for that post.  Usually that means that the post has been deleted.  It might also be locked, closed, etc.; the point is it is no longer sensible to do whatever the result of that flag would be.

Flagging a post to say that it's not an answer after it has already been deleted is obviously not productive for the moderators handling the flag, so they declined the flags.

You also should rarely be flagging posts in the Low quality posts queue.  You shouldn't ever be using the not an answer or very low quality flags in that queue.  *The point of those flags is to push the post into that queue*; if they're already there, the flag is clearly redundant.  The only real sensible flags to use in that queue are spam/offensive or a custom flag if the post requires moderator attention due to a problem that is beyond the community's capacity to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response - seems there's a gap in my SO knowledge. I did not know this - will accept once the cool-down period has passed.

Comment: @Luke - I apologize for the harsh wording on the decline reason, but we've seen a few people lately using flags from within the Low Quality Posts review queue to game helpful flags. We saw a number of flags that you had left immediately before you voted to delete posts, and it looked like that's what you were trying to do here. If it was merely a misunderstanding as to the purpose of flags, I'm sorry about the warning in the flag response.

Comment: as far as I can tell, [flag isn't really redundant](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281637/declined-flag-reasoning#comment136673_281637)

Comment: @gnat Clearly its conceptually redundant.  If you're voting to delete the post clearly you think it merits deletion.  Encouraging every reviewer to add yet another flag on top of that is not productive at all.  It's simply a behavior of the site that is encouraging abusive flagging patterns.  The solution to that is to fix the broken site behavior, not to encourage people to go around conducting abusive flagging patterns.

Comment: @Servy allowing a user to simultaneously flag and recommend deletion is simply a [bug, known and admitted by SE team](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204694/165773). Other than that, there is nothing _conceptually_ wrong when user picks one (not both) of either re-flag or recommend deletion, just for the reasons I laid out in prior comment

Comment: @BradLarson Hi Brad, thanks for the clarification. As has been discovered - I didn't know that if a post was about to be deleted then attempting to flag it would bring up limited options... oops :)

Answer (score 5):

I have a number of "declined" flags with the reason "found no evidence to support this", but the post has been handled the way I flagged it (e.g. deleted, or migrated to some site not in the close votes list).

One of the most reasonable declines I have seen was:

> declined - This is a low-quality post that should not be migrated anywhere.

but I also have posts that I flagged as "very low quality", where my flag is listed as "declined", but the post was deleted (not closed, but deleted) by a moderator... so I guess someone must have agreed with my flag...

My main reaction is "so what"... I don't see any consequences of flags being declined. It's mostly odd to see flags show up as declined, when the post that was flagged has been deleted. But I can imagine that some users will be discouraged when their flags get turned down like this.

Comment: I agree completely; but as an active user of the site, if there was something I was missing or misunderstood (which was the case) then I'd like to know what it was so I can correct my actions.

Comment: You're quite right about the discouragement. I've been trying to be a good citizen and work the review queues lately, and I've had a few flags declined, followed by the mods doing whatever I'd flagged it for anyway. I'm not trying to game anything: I'm just trying to help out, but the declines are really making me want to give up bothering with triage (which is hard enough work by itself).