# Concept of flags after you have 3k points

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, flag-badges

There is a gold badge `Marshal` which you can have after raising 500 helpful flags. When I was under **3k points** 10-20 flags per day was easy to do.

The problem came after the 3k threshold, I received the right to close questions. I can give 50 close votes per day, but none of them is counted as helpful flag. I understood that I can abuse the system if every close vote is counted as a helpful flag and this is not correct.

**Anyway I think that if my close vote leads to closing a bad question(that means 4 other guys vote this question to be closed too) this should be counted as a helpful flag. At the moment this is not happening.**

Comment: You can still flag comments, if you're looking for stuff to flag.

Comment: There's still plenty of things you can flag; spam immediately comes to mind.  Also, I think the most flags I've raised have been for egregiously off-topic questions, where I was the single close vote, and for whatever reason, my vote aged off and the question remains open.  I'll flag those explicitly stating, "Off-topic question; my close vote has expired" and get pretty good results.  Don't worry about chasing a badge though, it'll naturally happen over a long-enough time.

Comment: Yes, when you have the privilege to actually *do stuff* it's harder to get flags for telling other people to do stuff as now you have to actually do that stuff yourself.  This is why flags are, as a general rule, not nearly as helpful as so many other site actions.  Actually fixing a problem is just worth *so much more* than telling someone else to go fix a problem.

Comment: @Compass Flagging of answers is a bit of a problem because many times they are edited so much times that they are okay in their last state. In this case my flag is just disputed. Servy I'm getting your point, but most of the moderating by users is done for gamefication reasons and this bade is just losing his meaning.

Comment: FWIW at 2K+ rep one can make 100 helpful flags a day from VLQ queue by [re-flagging from outside of queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281637/declined-flag-reasoning/281638#comment136673_281637) instead of recommending deletion

Comment: @mybirthname So what?  If the badge looses meaning and people end up not performing unhelpful actions as a result, great.

Comment: @gnat Why are you trying to encourage people to abuse flags to inflate the flag count without actually being helpful?

Comment: @Servy it is not helpful only in your imagination (you just need to see some examples of garbage being dropped off review only because some kind soul picked looks-okay or edit)

Comment: I think there's two issues here: 1: Flags appear to become less important above 3K rep (not there yet). 2: The Marshal badge becomes harder to attain in gamification once you hit 3K rep. The second issue is NBD. The first issue could be important.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to flag, [I threw together this list a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172072/i-dont-flag-what-is-wrong-with-me/172075#172075).

Comment: @Compass I don't think that gamefication issue is not a big deal. If stackoverflow didn't have the top 10 chart for editing question do you think some guys are going to edit question everyday. Gamefication tool is really powerful, everybody wants to be first or seen as power user.

Comment: @bluefeet I will check it.

Comment: @mybirthname I consider it less of a concern than flags being useless. I doubt most people review questions in the hopes of getting on a Top 10 board, with the exception of the few people who are actually in range of being on that board.

Comment: For easy comment flags that don't even require a mod to review, you can use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/245986/search-for-short-comments?search=accept%20rate) Make sure to read the comment before flagging and then flag as not constructive or whatever since talk about accept rate is not constructive to the question/answers at hand, but only talking about an obsolete statistic that once appeared on user's profiles. If there is any valid info though other than the accept rate talk, then don't flag it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in the fact that there are more options to obtain a Marshal badge if you have under 3k rep. An interesting case, is [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal?userid=1355089) who has never even left a post or comment on SO, yet has the Marshal badge.

Some users never had much time to earn the 500 or 1000 rep from suggesting edits either, since their posts were really good and got them many reputation fairly quickly. So some users don't have the "benefit" of gaining rep through suggested edits anymore, they do "gain" the benefit of being able to edit posts without having them to be approved. Often times, suggested edits can conflict with another edit, so users can "waste" time and effort by suggesting a perfectly good edit, but they were just beat to it by another user.

Just because there is certain advantages/disadvantages with some things on the site depending on a user's reputation level doesn't mean that it's a "problem" per say. In pretty much every case it's [status-bydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

So because you now have the close vote "privilege", it means that your vote carries more weight than a "flag" vote. So your name can now appear in the list of users who got the question closed, and your vote is considered more valuable and your trusted enough now to use this extra power. Yes, you don't get "helpful" count for close votes since there not flags, but you get more power.

So there is no reason to add close votes as helpful since they are not flags and don't appear as a flag anymore in your flag history.

If you want to get marshal badge and help out on the site more, there are many other things to flag. You can flag Not an Answer posts that are left as answers. You can flag comments that are obsolete, not constructive, rude, etc. As well as custom mod flags for things that don't fit into an already existing flag reason, and that would need moderator attention.

Comment: @Deduplicator If you run out of close votes the system doesn't let you flag things for closing.  It tell you to come back in X hours.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes.  Once you run out of close votes you can't do any closing in the review queues.  Once you gain the vote privilege you can no longer flag for close reasons.  See this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283462/i-cant-mark-questions-as-unsalvageable-in-triage-when-im-out-of-close-votes-fo