# I can't mark questions as Unsalvageable in Triage when I'm out of Close votes for the day

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage

The title pretty much says it all; if I am out of close votes for the day, I cannot select the Unsalvageable > "it should be closed for another reason..." option in Triage.

This makes sense, since I ***am*** out of close votes for the day, but it leaves me with a conundrum:

- the question, in my opinion, *is* unsalvageable
- my remaining options are to:

  - mark the question as "Should be Improved", which is a huge understatement, or...
  - use the "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)", which I really don't want to do, since mods already have enough to do, and the question doesn't really require moderation interaction, just community interaction, or...
  - ignore the question and move on, which really bugs me, because I want to, nay, *need to*, take action on it.

It would be nice if there were some way to mark it as unsalvageable without requiring a vote to be cast, or at least mark it as unsalvageable when you've already burned through your close votes for the day.

And as Skuntsel reminded me, the inverse also applies:  if I vote to close an item, and it shows up in Triage later, I can't mark it as Unsalvageable.  Either I should be able to mark it as unsalvageable as above, or it simply shouldn't show up in the queue for me since I've already taken action on it.

Comment: Actually there is one more issue on a similar topic. If you voted to close a question via a close review queue or while viewing the question, you also won't have a chance to mark it as Unsalvageable if you happen to stumple upon it in the Triage queue. That's disappointing as that should be the outcome. I'd be glad to hear that this topic is going to be addressed.

Comment: @skuntsel - very true, I've had this happen a number of times as well

Comment: Can you edit that part into your question? It would be interesting to have some feedback on this issue as well (so that the question would be complete).

Comment: @skuntsel - edited

Comment: Can't you just, you know, not go into the Triage queue? :)

Comment: IMO, this is a problem because of the lack of maximum number of close votes users are allowed a day. It should be changed to 100, just like you get 100 flags a day for posts, and another 100 for comments at the maximum levels. Funny thing is.. close votes are 1/5th the weight of flags generally speaking.. yet you get less close votes.. it's a double whammy

Comment: Why can't you flag for closing when you're out of close votes? (Just like a user of <3000 rep would.)

Comment: @RyneEverett - I was under the impression that, except for extreme circumstances, it was frowned upon to flag questions for closing if you could go back and close it later after rollover.  Any time I've flagged a question to be closed (unless I explicitly state that I've voted for it to be closed already, and the close vote has expired), the flag has been rejected with "Does not require moderator attention, use your close votes."

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I completely agree with you.  The amount of questions in the Triage queue that require closing is quite large.  This SHOULD provide another tool to handle those poor quality questions.  Instead, it is cutting into the Close Votes question queue pool, which is already over-taxed with too few close votes available (to the active reviewers) to deal with the load.

Comment: Has there been any further discussion about this? It would be useful to at least be able to mark it without having to flag.

Comment: @Dzyann I don't know if there has been further discussion but it is still a problem - I just ran into it. Out of close votes for the day, allowed to review in Triage, unable to mark a question as Unsalvageable.

Comment: @RyneEverett The [flagging dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aPlth.png) is automatically converted to a voting one. It's literally impossible to flag to close after 3k. Reviewing triage and first posts queues becomes quite tedious after having burned most votes in the close queue. I never managed (nor actively tried) to use my 100 flags in a single day and they're even less usable now. Making the votes scale like flags or having extra review votes would be useful.

Answer (score 33):

I believe you should not be asked to process something in the queue, unless you are always able to choose the right way to handle it.

I guess we should go for either of these solutions:

1. Allow people to go over the limit if they are working the triage queue
2. Don't allow people to continue in the triage queue after they lose their ability to cast close votes

Option 1 would have my preference.

Comment: Option 3, once close votes are consumed, roll back to the Triage behaviour for reviewers with less than 3k rep - generate flags instead of close votes. Option 4, increase the daily ration of close votes.

Comment: @StephenKennedy I am not sure about option 3, but (a finite implementation of) option 4 definitely does not constitute a solution meet my core criterium: *you are always able to choose the right way to handle it* If you disagree, I would recommend posting this a separate answer.

Comment: I guess they really should Implement the 1st option since you are already entrusting the users who have access to this queue with something as serious as this so why not make their flags unlimited.

Answer (score 9):

As triage is currently an experimental queue and has no actual affect on posts, I dont see why we cant just mark items as unsalvageable without closing *when we run out of flags*. Lets not forget: **the primary goal of the triage queue is to gather data**, not to flag bad questions. The post flagging is an extra cherry on top.