# Is it OK to flag "Low Quality" posts when reviewing them from "review/low-quality-posts" section of site?

Tags: discussion

As you know, when reviewing [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) there are some options:
***Looks OK***, ***Edit***, ***Recommend Deletion*** and ***Skip***, Usually I review the post and do appropriate action, a few days ago one time when I opened the link of question to review more, I realized that I can also flag that specific post, I did it for 2-3 low quality posts and some hours later I saw that the number of my `helpful flags` has increased, I also thought that this is not right because this takes moderator's time and while I can do above mentioned actions I shouldn't take moderators time.

My question: What if a user use this way to increase his/her number of helpful flags and get reach related **Badges** fast? Is this way allowed? or this is a problem in SO and needs to be fixed?

Comment: related at MSE: [Flagging VLQ after opening the post in Low Quality queue but prior to recommending deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204694/165773)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What if a user use this way to increase his/her number of helpful
>   flags and get reach related Badges fast? Is this way allowed? or this
>   is a problem in SO and needs to be fixed?

If a user is caught doing this more than once or so, the user will likely be given a suspension. If I recall correctly, I remember reading somewhere on here fairly recently that they did a check of users gaming the system just in the way you described and those users were all given suspensions.

So this is definitely not something you should do. It doesn't help out the site at all to flag answers as NAA/LQ by opening those answers in a new link from the LQ review queue. Those answers being flagged (most of them, some are automated by the system) is what made them end up in that queue in the first place. So by flagging them again, you're really not helping out anything but your own helpful flag stat.

Comment: Related post where user received message that said "please stop gaming flags" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281637/3041194

Comment: Great, I knew that flagging again is not right, That's why I did it for only one or two or maybe three (not sure) posts.

Comment: But why did you even do that in the first place?

Comment: @LisaMM, `I was not sure`, I did it for only one or two posts, if I was sure then I didn't ask such this question. anyway.