# Our own flags marked 'helpful' after reviewing the post from the queue

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues, flags

A couple of times I've had the following sequence occur:

- Navigated through to a question where a low quality review answer was located.
- Flagged a different answer.
- The answer I flagged showed up in the queue a few items later and I recommended to delete it.
- The answer was deleted and my flag was marked 'helpful'.

Shouldn't reviewing an item we have placed a flag on invalidate the flag somehow?

This can be used to farm fraudulent 'helpful' flags:

- Find a review item that is a clear case to be deleted.
- Navigate to the item and place a (redundant) flag on it.
- Recommend to delete it from the queue.
- When the answer is deleted, your flag will be marked 'helpful'.

If this can't be prevented, reviewers can thank me for the tip by going to my profile and upvoting all my top answers.*

---

<sub>* joke</sub>

Comment: Yeah... Reviewing posts you've flagged is disabled in some other queues; will check to see if that's not being done here.

Comment: I think this might have come up before. The best solution IMHO would be that you could not review answers that you flagged. I'm not sure if you systematic exploit works because you don't control what answers you get to review. But since the LQ review queue is typically pretty short, it's quite common that I review answers I flagged myself if I do some reviewing after chasing down bad answers and flagging them.

Comment: @Shog9 I assume we could also place a flag *after* reviewing it too. Not sure if that is relevant to your comment.

Comment: @RetoKoradi It works systematically because you can flag it after it's been "discovered" in the queue. (I did it by mistake once: a user posted two identical LQ answers and I flagged the one I already reviewed.)

Comment: @Shog9 I'm quite certain it's not. I believe I got to review a post I flagged as recently as yesterday. That was in the LQ queue after flagging as NAA.

Comment: @Radiodef That sounds like a different exploit, more like this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291165/is-it-ok-to-flag-low-quality-posts-when-reviewing-them-from-review-low-qualit. Which is frowned upon.

Comment: @RetoKoradi That is pretty much the same thing I've described here, in the second part of my answer. Good to know they check for it sometimes I guess. I already know it's not OK, I think it should really be prevented.

Comment: So, there's a restriction in place to prevent you from being assigned a task in review that you've previously flagged, but nothing that'd prevent you from flagging it *while you're reviewing it*. Fixing that would be... Hard.