# Accidentally edited a low-quality answer, what should I do?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I recently reviewed some posts from the Low-Quality Queue and got this [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36104113/5466118) for review:

> yeah I added the "stopClk <= true;" line and it seems to be working now! thanks for all the help !

It looked like an answer to me, where I just had to strip of the noise. So, I edited the post to:

> I added the
>
> ```
> stopClk <= true;
> ```
>
> line and it seems to be working now.

Later on, I stumbled over the answer again and saw, that the answer was just a reply to another accepted answer. So, I down-voted the answer and left a comment explaining the situation:

> I improved this answer during the review process because I thought it was an answer. But, now I see, that it was just a reply to another post. Please delete your answer, it is not even helpful. StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. Just accept an answer as you have already done. Once you have enough reputation, you can also vote on answers.

Should I have recommend the answer for deletion in the first place?

Should I take any additional action?

According, to [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291165/is-it-ok-to-flag-low-quality-posts-when-reviewing-them-from-review-low-qualit), I should not flag it again.

Comment: I once edited a post by mistake that had been deleted already. These things happen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After your mistake in the queue, your actions were fine and totally appropriate. And, yes, you should flag again.

The Meta post you linked to is dealing with the potential abuse reviewers can make, that is, flagging the answer and then recommending deletion so that their helpful flags count increases. This is not the case here: in fact, when you edited the answer, it was pulled out of the "Low Quality Posts" queue so there can be no abuse.

You shouldn't have edited the post in the queue, and, instead, chose "Recommend Deletion":

> yeah I added the "stopClk <= true;" line and it seems to be working now! thanks for all the help !

The end of the post implies that this is a "Thank you" answer directed at another post of the question. In this case, best to investigate further by actually looking at the question and all of its answers to see if it is actually the case or not.

It can happen that, sometimes, there are no other answers and the OP is refering to comments that were left. Sometimes there aren't even comments, and the "thanks" is just there as fluff. In such a scenario, you should edit and remove the fluff, exactly like you did. (Also, the answer shouldn't have been flagged to begin with, but, unfortunately, it happens...)

But when there are another answer and it is clear that it is directed at another answer, don't edit and recommend deletion. It would be "Not An Answer" and the appropiate comment to leave would be:

> “Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.”

Comment: I would add that peeking at the OP's rep beforehand is a good idea. Recommending up-voting to someone who cannot perform the action is just confusing. Recommending 'accepting' one of the proposed solutions as an answer would be more appropriate in any event with an additional 'up-vote if found helpful' comment secondary. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Jeeped Recent revisions to the LQP autocomments address your concern.

Comment: I'd just like to note that this is yet another example of review confusion that could've been avoided if we could [see other answers to the question in review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue). (And yes, I have [a user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) that implements that feature.:)

Comment: For people who do not use user scripts, the question's title is a link and the context (right click) menu of some browsers offers "open in new window (or tab)". Hence the whole Q&A can be viewed without leaving the review.