# Why was this flag declined for plagiarized answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, plagiarism

I flagged a question for not an answer (**NAA**) where a user just copy pasted an already written answer and added thank you to the OP (here the thank you part is the only thing written by the user other that whole answer is copy pasted of an already-written answer).

Plagiarized answer with thank you comment:
[Swift Continuous Rotation Animation not so continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964346/swift-continuous-rotation-animation-not-so-continuous/42618705#42618705)

Original answer:
[Swift Continuous Rotation Animation not so continuous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964346/swift-continuous-rotation-animation-not-so-continuous/41160100#41160100)

How should I have flagged that answer instead, if at all?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention with a custom flag.

Comment: I was the one who declined that. The reasons have already been variously posted below: moderators see the post without context and in an abbreviated manner; unless you clearly spell out what I'm supposed to be looking at it's easy to mistake, which unfortunately happened here. At first glance it totally looks like an answer since it contains a bunch of relevant code. A custom flag would have been easier to judge correctly. Your flag wasn't necessarily incorrect though either.

Comment: Another reason for the custom mod flag: If you include the word "plagiarism" in the explanation, I'm told the flag gets expedited. Which makes sense.

Comment: @deceze Ahh, I was waiting for you, I have one more question does every flag was seen by moderator or only some special flag like NAA and VLQ, It will help me next time.

Comment: It's… complicated. Primarily flags are supposed to be handled by the community in the various review queues; but they will bubble into the moderator queue after some time/severity/whatever other criteria are applied today. Certain flags like rude/abusive or spam immediately jump to the top of the moderator queue, and there are no community queues for them.

Answer (score 62):

If you think you've found plagiarism, use a custom moderator flag and explain the problem.

Anyone processing a NAA flag will only be shown that one answer and at first glance it does look like it might be an answer, it has some code and is does not solely consist of the thanks which would make it clearly a NAA candidate.

An answer is an answer even if it's plagiarised so NAA is not an appropriate flag type for plagiarism.

If you know something that needs to be or should be communicated in order to process a flag then a moderator flag is the only one that allows additional information to be added.

Comment: What about "thank you" comment at the end of answer It is way of thanking you with copied content seems NAA to me first.

Comment: It *is* NAA because it's a thank-you comment. Though it's also copied content, so it should be deleted for two reasons.

Comment: @Floern It isn't **just** a thank-you comment though. It's a complicated enough situation that a custom flag explaning to a moderator what you've found in detail is appropriate.

Comment: The problem is more in the way how flags are handled. In the review queue for NAA, you only see this one answer. Without additional comment is is very hard to spot that there is a second similar answer.

Comment: @BDL that is the key: if you need context to judge a flag, use a custom flag.

Comment: Also I am not just talking about plagiarism it has thank you comment!

Comment: A "thank you" comment doesn't make an answer NAA. It should be edited out, but there is no need to delete just because there is a "thank you" included.

Comment: The contrary @BDL. The thank you is the reason it should have been deleted, and the NAA flag accepted. There is even a canned reason for this.

Comment: I've seen "real answers" written with a "thank you" at the end because the author of the answer relied on comments or other answers to produce their own different answer. So the presence of a "thank you" is not determinative. It is only after knowing that most of the answer is a copy of an earlier one that it becomes nothing more than a thank you and NAA. You need context here. As rene said, "if you need context to judge a flag, use a custom flag".

Comment: @Tunaki: There is a canned reason for questions that **only** consist of a "thank you". If I would only look at that single answer without any context (as it would be in the review queue), then it isn't apparently clear that it is NAA. There are a lot of valid answers that have a lot of code and a "worked for me" text. Without seeing that there is a second, earlier answer with the same code it looks like a valid answer.

Comment: @BDL Meh, I've raised thousands of flags on "thank you" answers, without hitting any declined flags. Moderators don't need to be taken by the hand all the time like children on cases like those. [Everyone is expected to do that already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319373/1743880), reviewers included.

Comment: The intention of the post was to say "thank you", so it's not an attempt to answer. But yes, because of the improperly quoted code, it looks like a real answer with a "thank you" signature line (as viewed from the review queue without context).

Comment: You got a lot of upvote's but stating *"NAA is not an appropriate flag type"* on this answer can't be correct, stating you better use custom mod flag for this answer since it is hard to see that it is an NAA I think would be more appropriate.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I've tried to make things clearer.

Comment: @Floern "as viewed from the review queue without context"? Wut? The review queue shows context by default, the only queue that doesn't do that is mods queue.

Comment: @Braiam well, not everything. You wouldn't see the other answers.

Answer (score 23):

Looking at the answer for the first time (I didn't handle your flag), I had a hard time figuring out where exactly the "thank you" portion of the answer was — turns out, it was in the same code block as the rest of the code that the user had copied and pasted into their answer, which they did as an attempt at "quoting" the answer.

When a user either goes out of their way to make their post hard to decipher, or is so spectacularly in over their head at figuring out how formatting on the site works... that's something you've really gotta spell out for everyone.

When you encounter a thank-you answer that (attempts to) quote the answer the user is thanking in such a way that it's not immediately obvious it's simply a thank-you answer, feel free to use the following as a template when flagging it:

> This is not an answer, but an attempt at thanking an existing answer by copying it.

(You could also just call it plagiarism, but that doesn't exactly work with the rare thank-you answer that somehow manages to get the quote formatting and attribution right... I could have sworn I've handled at least one such case.)

Comment: I didn't noticed at first too and I ask her for clarification of code and she pointed me to original answerer herself so I am not sure that she wrote the answer for garnering rep so she might be innocently want to thank you with example of the op.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Yeah, it's pretty clear the OP wasn't trying to plagiarize, but to "reply inline" to the original answer, much like you'd do on a forum.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Not surprising.  I've had people tell me "No, actually, SO *is* a forum.  Questions are posts and answers are replies" after I point out that SO is not a forum.  You can lead a horse to water...

Answer (score 11):

Generally speaking, when using one of the standard flags, especially "Very Low Quality" and "Not An Answer", it should be immediately obvious when looking at the answer on its own why it was flagged.  In this case, the "thank you comment" might have been a clue, but it probably wasn't immediately obvious why it was flagged as "Not an Answer".  If it isn't immediate obvious, you still may have success using the standard flags, but the chances of the flag getting declined or the wrong action getting taken increases.

Anytime it isn't obvious or you think the reason you are flagging it requires more explanation, a custom flag explaining why you are flagging and and what action you are expecting the moderator to do is appropriate.  You should include links, if needed.

Answer (score -5):

That is not plagiarism. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42618705/1743880) ends with:

> worked for me perfectly. thank you keval!

Quoting the answer that helped them (or just copy-pasting it) happens quite frequently in new answers to old questions, that only consists in thanking the other answer. The intent of that post was not to plagiarize, but just to say thanks.

The NAA flag, on the other hand, was perfectly valid, and there is no reason it should have been declined. When faced with such a situation (post ending with "Thanks"), it is expected that both moderators, and reviewers, [gather more context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319373/1743880). And thanking an answer in another post is, [by definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), not an answer (Reason #1: "Thanking the posters").

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137597/discussion-on-answer-by-tunaki-flag-declined-for-plagiarized-answer).